# MySQL Workbench - Counting Specific Rows

Tags: mysql-workbench

You know in SQL Developer, let's say a query returned 100 rows.  Of those 100 rows you could ctrl shift and highlight just a portion of them then right click on that highlighted section and click count to get a total of the highlighted section.  Any way to do that in MySQL Workbench?

On a side note, I can't believe they don't allow line numbering in the results section.  It'd be a HUGE help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there no way you could get your query to give you the rows that you are selecting. If you can do it manually I'm pretty sure you can run a query to return the results.

Comment: Sure, that's easy enough, just less convenient that SQL Developer's way.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you have to use MySQL Workbench ? 
for example HeidiSQL counts the rows you are selecting

When I first installed Mysql, mysql workbench was installed with it but I wasn't convinced, so I installed HeidiSQL and I'm fully satisfied.